# About a sum of Legendre symbols associated to an odd prime

Tags: number-theory, summation, legendre-symbol

Let $p$ be an odd prime, and put $$s(a, p) = 
\sum_{n=1}^{p} \left(\frac{n(n+a)}{p}\right) $$

Show that:

(i)  $s(0, p) = p − 1$

(ii)  $\sum_{a=1}^{p}s(a, p) = 0.$

(ii) If $(a, p) = 1$ then $ s(a, p) = s(1, p).$

(iii) Conclude that $s(a, p) = −1$ if $(a, p) = 1.$

Is it enough for me for ii) to say that if $n>0$ and $s>0$ then the $\sum(s)>0$ hence cannot be true

Im not sure what to do for the other ones

Comment: $f_a(n) = n(n+a)$. Find some $b,c,d$ such that $f_a(bn+c) =  d f_1(n) \bmod p$.

Comment: hey thanks but would that be for ii)

Comment: is i) true? for example $s(0,3) = \sum_{n=1}^3 \frac {n^2}{3} = \frac 13 + \frac 43 + 3 $ which is obviously not 2. In general the last term for $ s(0,p)$ is $p > p-1$ unless I'm missing something...

Answer (score 1):

Notice that
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{p}\left(\frac{n(n+a)}{p}\right)=\sum_{n=1}^{p-1}\left(\frac{n^{-1}(n+a)}{p}\right)=\sum_{n=1}^{p-1
}\left(\frac{1+a n^{-1}}{p}\right)=\sum_{m=1}^{p-1}\left(\frac{1+am}{p}\right). $$
If $a$ is a multiple of $p$ the RHS is just $p-1$. Otherwise $m\mapsto am$ gives a permutation of $\mathbb{Z}/(p\mathbb{Z})^*$ and the RHS equals
$$ \sum_{s=1}^{p-1}\left(\frac{1+s}{p}\right)=\sum_{s=1}^{p-2}\left(\frac{1+s}{p}\right)=-1+\sum_{s=1}^{p-1}\left(\frac{s}{p}\right)=-1. $$